# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having the following error in my app :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.
ViewHolder 1:ViewHolder{c7b44d1 position=5 id=3, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 not recyclable(1)} 
View Holder 2:ViewHolder{67232f6 position=3 id=3, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1}
```

I'm using MaterialDrawer from Mike @github, this is my viewholder sample :

```
public class FavoritesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView Title;
ImageView Pic;

public FavoritesViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHighlight);
    Pic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHighlight);

   }
}
```

Two fragments are switching their layout, when i press the first, it load without any problem, when i press the second fragment, it load a different layout and FC itself.

Both fragmets use the same ViewHolder code but in different classes .

Comment: are you sure that your id are stable and unique for each item?

Comment: Noobie question : Where to find that id ? i didn't come across any a similar thing at all.

Comment: check whether getItemId() return same for 2  viewholder, also check if you title same for 2 viewholders?

Comment: Both Viewholders have different class name, I just modified the class code, used different variables names, it worked now, i don't think that's the problem but it's fixed now, thanks!.

Comment: the problem was 2 viewholder having same id you must be passing something that result in same id in 2 viewholder in the lib that was the issue

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got this error when manipulated list items (changed their positions), but made a mistake. I tried to create a copy of an item and add it to the top:

```
val oldItem = adapter.getItem(id)
val newItem = oldItem.copy(text = "item updated")
adapter.removeItem(7) // Removed nothing.
adapter.addItem(0, newItem) // Added the item with the same id.
```

I wanted to remove the 7th item instead of the item with the given `id`. So, I didn't remove anything (`removeItem` works so in my code).Then I added a new item with the same `id`. Now the list contains two equal items and throws the error. So, correct an error to have unique `id`s.

If you don't know where equal `id`s appear, you can do this.

Set `adapter.setHasStableIds(false)` and after it assign an adapter of `RecyclerView`:

```
with(view.recycler_view) {
    layoutManager = this@YourFragment.layoutManager
    adapter = this@YourFragment.adapter
    setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

If you set `setHasStableIds(false)` after `RecyclerView`, you will get an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460141/cannot-change-whether-this-adapter-has-stable-ids-while-the-adapter-has-register).

These two `ViewHolder`s can be of the same class, not different.

Answer (score -3):

remove your code `setHasStableIds`, because recyclerView has a  reuse mechanism