# Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView in my android project and its performance has been really awful. From the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188536/recyclerview-scrolling-performance), I tried adding `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);` to my code. When running, I got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers.
```

My full logCat is as below;

```
09-22 22:22:23.634 1808-1808/com.revosleap.movielist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.revosleap.movielist, PID: 1808
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers.
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.setHasStableIds(RecyclerView.java:6749)
    at com.revosleap.movielist.Utils.UrlUtils.GenreFetcher.getGenre(GenreFetcher.java:48)
    at com.revosleap.movielist.MainActivity$2.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:221)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:1124)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:54)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:1089)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Can you share you code first?

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio , do you mean my adapter or what the method where am handling the recyclerview?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You must set the adapter's hasStableIds to true BEFORE you assign the adapter to your recyclerview.

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter();
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 12):

as the recyclerView source code:

```
    /**
     * Indicates whether each item in the data set can be represented with a unique identifier
     * of type {@link java.lang.Long}.
     *
     * @param hasStableIds Whether items in data set have unique identifiers or not.
     * @see #hasStableIds()
     * @see #getItemId(int)
     */
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        if (hasObservers()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot change whether this adapter has "
                    + "stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers.");
        }
        mHasStableIds = hasStableIds;
    } .
```

so you can workaround it .

```
    if (!adapter.hasObservers()) {
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);` with ObservableArrayList/ObservableFields

Comment: What should I do now pls?

Comment: Yes of course you can

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because the I put the `setHasStableIds(true)` inside the Fragment's `onActivityCreated()`. The `Fragment` is the main point of my application so it never gets popped from back stack.

```
class LocalFragment: Fragment() {
    private val adapter = LocalAdapter()
 
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the `onActivityCreated()` is called every time the `Fragment` is navigated to. However, as the Fragment is still alive in the back stack, the `private val adapter` field is still the same object that had its `setStableIds(true)` called previously.

```
class LocalFragment: Fragment() {
    private var adapter = LocalAdapter()
 
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        adapter = LocalAdapter() // Re-assign the adapter
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
    }
}
```

Solution is to reassign the `RecyclerView.Adapter` object every time the fragment is switched to.