# RecyclerView item selection is throwing error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I tried to implement the item selection feature in *RecyclerView* with the help of *SelectionTracker* but getting *IllegalArgumentException* and the stacktrace is not intuitive as it only shows the metadata.

*this is how I am building the tracker*

```
wordAdapter.tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
                "mySelectionId",
                recyclerView,
                new StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView),
                new MyDetailsLookUp(recyclerView),
                StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        ).withSelectionPredicate(
                SelectionPredicates.<Long>createSelectAnything()
        ).build();
```

*MyDetailsLookUp* class

```
class MyDetailsLookUp extends ItemDetailsLookup<Long> {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        MyDetailsLookUp(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
            View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (view != null) {
                //  getting individual view holders
                return ((WordAdapter.MyViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view)).getItemDetails();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

*getItemDetails* method in *ViewHolder* in the *WordAdapter*

```
ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(){
            return new ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>(){
                @Override
                public int getPosition() {
                    return getAdapterPosition();
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Long getSelectionKey() {
                    return getItemId();
                }
            };
        }
```

**Stacktrace 1**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
        at androidx.recyclerview.selection.DefaultSelectionTracker.anchorRange(DefaultSelectionTracker.java:269)
        at androidx.recyclerview.selection.MotionInputHandler.selectItem(MotionInputHandler.java:60)
        at androidx.recyclerview.selection.TouchInputHandler.onLongPress(TouchInputHandler.java:132)
        at androidx.recyclerview.selection.GestureRouter.onLongPress(GestureRouter.java:96)
        at android.view.GestureDetector.dispatchLongPress(GestureDetector.java:778)
        at android.view.GestureDetector.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:293)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Surprisingly, I have implemented the same code in Kotlin and it is working fine there. I found a SO post with the similar problem [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460141/cannot-change-whether-this-adapter-has-stable-ids-while-the-adapter-has-register), the accepted answer suggesting a custom *ItemKeyProvider* to be passed instead of *StableIdKeyProvider*. Therefore, on doing so hit me with this error.

**Stacktrace 2**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.
     ViewHolder 1:ViewHolder{987472c position=1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1} 
     View Holder 2:ViewHolder{e50e5f5 position=2 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 not recyclable(1)} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{617d73 VFED..... .F....ID 42,42-1038,1542 #7f08007b app:id/recyclerview}, adapter:com.example.roomwordssample.WordAdapter@7ada430, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@a15b8a9, context:com.example.roomwordssample.Main2Activity@ca1d275
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.handleMissingPreInfoForChangeError(RecyclerView.java:4058)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3982)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3652)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1877)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

*updated tracker*

```
wordAdapter.tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
                "mySelectionId",
                recyclerView,
               new GetItemDetails(recyclerView, ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_MAPPED),
                new MyDetailsLookUp(recyclerView),
                StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        ).withSelectionPredicate(
                SelectionPredicates.<Long>createSelectAnything()
        ).build();
```

*CustomItemKeyProvider*

```
class CustomItemKeyProvider extends ItemKeyProvider<Long> {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        CustomItemKeyProvider(RecyclerView recyclerView, int scope) {
            super(scope);
            this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Long getKey(int position) {
            return wordAdapter.getItemId(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getPosition(@NonNull Long key) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(key);
            return viewHolder == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
        }
    }
```

*P.S*: `wordAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)` is done before setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView`

Comment: As your Adapter has stable id, it must return unique Id for each adapter position. How do you return that Id now?

Answer (score 0):

In your stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.
     ViewHolder 1:ViewHolder{987472c **position=1 id=-1**, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1} 
     View Holder 2:ViewHolder{e50e5f5 **position=2 id=-1**, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 not recyclable(1)}
```

In above error it says for position 1 and 2 in list, you are using same ID but it has to be unique. In order to use with selection Tracker, ensure you have unique id.
 Inform list that you have stable ID

`setHasStableIds(true)`

In RecyclerView.Adapter you need to sure you are using unique for each

```
public abstract class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
  private List<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
  //other override methods

  @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position; // here each value must be unique either position or data unique id
    }
}
```